# media query device width or resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my media queries.

I am targeting (to start with) a max-device-width of 1024px with one stylesheet, and min-device-width of 1025px with another, then using percentages so the content adapts to the browser resizing.

However, my large 20inc screen uses the same stylesheet as my 11.6inch screen, I assume this is due to resolution as my old computer with a 15inch screen uses the other, smaller stylesheet?

Because I am usingpercentages for my main content area, this area appears fine on my large screen as clearly I don't want the content spread over my whoe 20inch screen, but on my small 11.6inch screen it looks tiny.

What am I doing wrong? Is there best practice for targeting devices and is using percentages a viable option? I like the way my content adapts to the browser resizing bit by bit.

I understand a decent amount about how media wueries work, but would love to have a method that I could use for most sites, be it using device-width, width or resolution etc, as at the minute I find I need to keep adding stylesheets.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use `min-width` / `max-width` over `min-device-width` / `max-device-width`.

If the reader has a big resolution screen, `max-device-width` will return the width of his total screen resolution, rather than the width of his actual browser window.

Comment: or you can use both.  @media screen and (min-width:Xpx),screen and (min-device-width:Xpx) {}

Comment: another thing to take into account is that, if the user zooms in or out (ctrl + or ctrl -) in their browser, then the min-width and max-width values change (as if the screen was smaller or bigger)

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your 11.6 inch screen has a high pixel density screen (HiDPI). This would give it a resolution almost equal to your 20 inch screen. Thus they would have the same style (max-device-width/min-device-width) try targeting devices in terms of DPI, or pixel-ratios. 
*See this guide for more (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).*

Also you may need to add a viewport to adjust your text size. A well-recommened statement for your `<head>` tag is (http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```